# Django: Set foreign key using integer?

Tags: django, optimization, django-models, foreign-keys

Is there a way to set foreign key relationship using the integer id of a model?  This would be for optimization purposes.

For example, suppose I have an Employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  type = models.ForeignKey('EmployeeType')
```

and

```
EmployeeType(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want the flexibility of having unlimited employee types, but in the deployed application there will likely be only a single type so I'm wondering if there is a way to hardcode the id and set the relationship this way.  This way I can avoid a db call to get the EmployeeType object first.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Yep:

```py
employee = Employee(first_name="Name", last_name="Name")
employee.type_id = 4
employee.save()
```

`ForeignKey` fields store their value in an attribute with `_id` at the end, which you can access directly to avoid visiting the database.

The `_id` version of a `ForeignKey` is a particularly useful aspect of Django, one that everyone should know and use from time to time when appropriate.

**caveat:** [ < Django 2.1 ]

@RuneKaagaard points out that `employee.type` is not accurate afterwards in recent Django versions, even after calling `employee.save()` (it holds its old value). Using it would of course defeat the purpose of the above optimisation, but I would prefer an accidental extra query to being incorrect. So be careful, only use this when you are finished working on your instance (eg `employee`).

**Note**: As @humcat points out below, the bug is fixed in [Django 2.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ee49306176a2d2f1751cb890bd607d42c7c09196)

Comment: [model `.save()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/db/models/base.py#L708) uses the field `attname` ([`pre_save()` returns the `attname` value](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L602)). For ForeignKeys, `attname` is the name with `_id` suffix. Also, the `foobar_id` attribute of a model instance is [automatically updated](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L467) when you set `foobar`. But where is it officially documented?

Comment: Using foreign key values directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly

Comment: I tested this on Django 1.7 today, and it's not a good idea there. While it works, and the `type` field gets written to the database, if you access the `type` property afterwards it doesn't reflect the change. Said in code, this would fail `assert(employe.type.id == 4)`.

Comment: @RuneKaagaard Wow, I didn't expect that. I expected Django to perform an SQL query when accessing the attribute and returning the relevant `Type` instance. But it didn't, it returned the value from when the `Employee` instance was created. I this this is a bug in Django, I would prefer inefficient to incorrect, I'll report it.

Comment: @WillHardy Exactly, got bitten by that today, when logging a change in a FK field. I thinks Django means the `_id` shortcut to be readonly, and at least it should be documented as such.

Comment: my workaround to the problem @RuneKaagaard mentioned is to also invalidate the cached value of the related object. This is quite ugly because it touches the innards of the Django Model, but it works: `if hasattr(employee, '_type_cache'): delattr(employee, '_type_cache')`

Comment: @AmichaiSchreiber I believe the next release of Django will have a fix for this problem: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27710

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future, this problem is fixed in [Django 2.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ee49306176a2d2f1751cb890bd607d42c7c09196).

Answer (score 56):

An alternative that uses [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) to create the object and save it to the database in one line:

```
employee = Employee.objects.create(first_name='first', last_name='last', type_id=4)
```

Comment: Does this call the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Just to emphasize something on the accepted answer (based on my experience):
When you want to add a value in the "id" field of the foreign key (hope that this is clear), you must add "_id" at the end of the name defined by you in that class.

In this example:
employee = Employee(first_name="Name", last_name="Name", type**_id**=4)

Here "type" refers to "type" defined in the "Employee" class.

Note that if you have defined something like "foo_id", you still must add the "_id" suffix and the result will be "foo_id_id"

PS: I can't comment or do other actions (not enough reputation points)