# Django model object with foreign key creation

Tags: django, django-models

Hi
Suppose I have a simple model class like this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    testkey = models.ForeignKey(TestModel2)
    ...
```

When I am creating a TestModel object I have to pass to it an instance of the TestModel2 object to create it:

```
testkey =TestModel2.objects.get(id=...)
TestModel.objects.create(testkey=testkey)
```

This results in 2 queries to database I suppose, and I have a list of Foreign key IDs that I need to create objects with.

Is it possible to create objects with foreign keys without initially retrieving the foreign key objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Set foreign key using integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

What you’re after is:

```
TestModel.objects.create(testkey_id=1)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, but for some reason it does not work with get_or_create :(

Comment: @dragon: I believe TestModel2.objects.get(testkey_id=1) doesn't work either.

Comment: @Tomasz no, that won’t work, but `TestModel2.objects.get(testkey__id=1)`, and `TestModel2.objects.get_or_create(testkey__id=1)` will work (note the double underscore). It’s very possible though that these will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

Comment: What if the foreign key has a to_field value that is different than "id"?

Comment: @kloddant as far as I can tell, the field is always called `«foreign-key-name»_id` regardless of `to_field` or the primary-key of the related model.

Comment: @sneeu, Thanks!  Yes, I have confirmed this just yesterday by testing it out.  It is indeed «foreign-key-name»_id, regardless of the to_field.

Answer (score 19):

In my case `TestModel.objects.create(testkey__id=1)` didn't work for me so I had to put one underscore instead of two, for example

`TestModel.objects.create(testkey_id=1)`

Comment: confirm, single underscore seems to work (Django 3.1.7)

Comment: According to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846537/2089675), this is the correct method

Answer (score 14):

In `get_or_create` it will fail in get. So to make `get_or_create` work below is the solution:

```
TestModel.objects.get_or_create(testkey=TestModel2(id=1))
```

Reference:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13915

Comment: This worked for me. The double underscore, "testkey__id=1", method mentioned above did not work. Thx.