# Django: How to access session_key in middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'm unable to access the `session_key` in my custom Django middleware. I try to access it using:

```
session = Session.objects.get(pk=request.session._session_key)
```

or

```
session_key = request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
session = Session.objects.get(pk=session_key)
```

I get the error:

```
Session matching query does not exist.
```

I have put my middleware at the end of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and after `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in my `settings.py` file.

I can set session keys in the middleware, but it appears as if the session_key is only generated/accessible after the full page is displayed. Because when the page is displayed for the first time `{{ request.session.session_key }}` returns `None` in my template. When I refresh the page I get to see the `session_key`. Any tips on how I can access the `session_key` are very welcome.

Comment: Why would you do that query? Why not just access `request.session` directly?

Comment: I have a table that references the django_session table like:
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)

When I create an instance of it, using request.session for example it gives me the following error: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x00000000025CC518>": "Visitor.session" must be a "Session" instance.

That is why I am trying to query the session table in order to get a "Session" instance.

Comment: Do you actually have a session key when you are hitting the db? New sessions are being created only in `process_response` on the session middleware - because they need to store anything from the view, and can't do that before the view is fully processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. It turns out that normally the session is only saved after the complete page is rendered.

I managed to save the session prematurely in my middleware using:

```
request.session.save()
```

I could then save my model like (note the _id after session, which allows you to set the [foreign key using only an integer or varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer) in my case):

```
visitor = Visitor()
visitor.session_id = request.session.session_key
visitor.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with the following, does it work for you?

```
Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key)
```

If not, perhaps @ilvar is correct that you attempting to access the session before it is active.