# django: getting foreign key information

Tags: django, model

I created a model with couple of classes and with foreign key and I was able to save it on the database.

I have the following models:

```
class Player_Bios(models.Model):
  my_id            = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  player_id        = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, unique=True)    
  name             = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
  last             = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  middle           = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class BatStat (models.Model):
  player_id           = models.ForeignKey('Player_Bios')
  team_id             = models.ForeignKey('Team')
  bat_stat_id         = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  sport_code           = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) 
  ab                  = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Team (models.Model):

  team_id             = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  team_short          = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  team_full           = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

When I save it to the database I can see that the team_id on the Team table is the same as the team_id on the BatStat table, but the player_id on the BatStat is different that the player_id on the Player_Bios table. This is how I save the data to the database:

```
p_id = Player_Bios.objects.get(player_id=st['player_id'])
t_id = Team.objects.get(team_id=st['team_id']) #I get the team_id from the Team Class
bat_id = str(st['season'])+ str(st['team_seq'])
bat_id = str(p_id.player_id) + bat_id
c = BatStat(player_id = p_id,team_id=t_id, bat_stat_id=bat_id, sport_code =st["sport_code"],ab=st['ab'])
c.save()
```

st['player_id'] is a dictionary. I did a print and it show the right player_id number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BatStat you are storing the key to Player_Bios, which is not player_id

```
class Player_Bios(models.Model):
  ...
  player_id        = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, unique=True)  

class BatStat (models.Model):
  ...
  player_id           = models.ForeignKey('Player_Bios')
```

I'm not sure why your team_id is the same, however, it seems like you already have the ids. You could avoid looking up the Player_Bios and Team by setting the id directly.

[Django: Set foreign key using integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer)

```
class Player_Bios(models.Model):
  ...
  player_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)  

class Team (models.Model):
  ...
  team_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)

class BatStat (models.Model):
  ...
  player = models.ForeignKey('Player_Bios') # notice i renamed this to not have '_id'
  team = models.ForeignKey('Team') # notice i renamed this to not have '_id'

c = BatStat(bat_stat_id=bat_id, 
            sport_code =st["sport_code"],
            ab=st['ab'])
c.player_id = st['player_id'], # notice that this has '_id'
c.team_id = st['team_id'], # notice this has '_id'
c.save()
```

Comment: Why the team_id is take it, but not the player_id?

Comment: Am I doing it the wrong way? or it is suppose to work like this? I'm not a database guru. Thanks

Comment: You don't show how you are assigning the team_id in your example so I'm not sure what is happening there.

Comment: Never mind, the same thing with team_id. Do you think I should change it as you suggested or leave like this? Thanks

Comment: I don't really have enough information about your database/app structure to tell you what you should and shouldn't do. Maybe post another question explaining your situation and asking for suggestions?