# Django model inserting foreign key from same model

Tags: django-models

I am building a simple comment app in Django.  The app allows replies to comments and uses the same model to store comments and replies.  My issues is when I try to insert a new reply, the parentpost(FK to parent comment) inserts as NULL. When I use the admin interface to insert a reply, it properly stores the parentpost ID for the parentpost I choose.  So I know the issue is not within my model but within my view.

/*MODEL*/

```
class UserPost(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                        help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.', editable = False)


post = models.TextField()
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True,
                                 help_text='Content for description meta tag')
meta_description = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True, null = True,
                                    help_text = 'Content for description meta tag')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
parentpost = models.ForeignKey('self', blank = True, null = True)

class Meta:
    #app_label = ''

    db_table = 'userposts'
    ordering = ['created_at']
    verbose_name_plural = 'UserPosts'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

@models.permalink   
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('lync_posts', (), {'posts_slug': self.slug})

def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        d = datetime.datetime.now()
        s = d.strftime('%Y-%M-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f')

        slugfield = str(self.name + s)
        self.slug = slugfield

        super(UserPost, self).save()
```

/*VIEW*/

```
def reply(request, slugIn):

parentpostIn = UserPost.objects.get(slug = slugIn)

pid = parentpostIn.id
template_name = 'reply.html'

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ReplyPostForm(data = request.POST)
    # create a new item

    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
        if form.is_valid():
            nameIn = form.cleaned_data['name']
            postIn = form.cleaned_data['post']

            newPost = UserPost(name = nameIn, post = postIn, parentpost = pid)
            newPost.save()
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

else:
    # This the the first page load, display a blank form
    form = forms.NewPostForm()

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I have ID: {{parentpostIn.id}} in my template and that correctly identifies the ID but the insert for the child post does not insert it as the ForeignKey.  So my view is accessing the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the parentpost ForeignKey by id.

You should either use:

```
newPost = UserPost(name = nameIn, post = postIn, parentpost = parentpostIn)
```

or (see [Django: Set foreign key using integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer)):

```
newPost = UserPost(name = nameIn, post = postIn)
newPost.parentpost_id = pid
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Quick question.  I was messing in the admin and using the foreign key field, what would cause the admin not to be able to update the parent post?  Say I have a child post that parent post is Test1 and when I try to update the parentpost to Test2 after I hit save, the post still shows Test1???