# Django foreign key in manager's create function

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Apologies if this is a really stupid question...

Say I have a model and manager, like this,

```
class TestModel_1Manager (models.Manager):
    def create (self, tk)
        m = self.model(test_key=tk)

class TestModel_1 (models.Model):
    test_key = models.ForeignKey ('TestModel_2')
    objects = TestModel_1Manager
```

Several questions:

1. Is this right at all?
2. If this is right, then the `models.ForeignKey` field does NOT take
   an object? Just a simple id integer is fine? That is, I don't need
   to do this: `m =
   self.model(test_key=TestModel_1.objects.get(id=tk))` or something
   like that?

Maybe I don't quite get what this `models.ForeignKey` actually is... an integer or some object reference?

Thanks!!

EDIT: just found this post [Django: Set foreign key using integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer?rq=1), wondering if it's relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` is an abstraction. *The field's* value is another object, but it is represented [*in the table*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) as the value of the PK of that object.

Comment: So... which one is right? `m = self.model(test_key=tk)` is this right? Or `m = self.model(test_key=TestModel_1.objects.get(id=tk))` ?

Comment: `m = self.model(test_key_id=tk)`