# How to add object to a one to many relationship in django?

Tags: python, django

I am building a django web app which requires a one to many model relationship. I read the docs and it says to use a `ForeignKey` in the model field.

In my case every user needs to have a one to many field with the job model which will keep track of completed jobs by that user.

Which in django I believe is represented like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    job_history = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The job model looks like this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="jobs")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    pay = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={
            'job_pk': self.id
            }
        )
```

In my view I want to add a job to the `job_history` one to many field. I do not know how to write this however. This is my view so far:

```
@login_required
def job_hire(request, account_pk, job_pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(account_pk)
    job = get_object_or_404(job_pk)

    # I now need to save the job object in the one to many field of the user object. But how?

    messages.success(request, "You have hired an applicant.")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs:find'))
```

How do I add the job to the one to many field in the user model to save the users jobs?

Answer (score 2):

It is redundant that a `User` points to a `Job` and a `Job` points to a `User` as you can [follow relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

The `user` field on the `Job` should be enough.
You still can lookup all jobs for a `User` via:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.jobs.all()  # shows all jobs for the user.
```

(Note that it would be `user.job_set.all()` if you hadn't set a related name to `jobs`)

So in your view this should be enough:

```
@login_required
def job_hire(request, account_pk, job_pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=account_pk)
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_pk)
    job.user = user
    job.save()
```

Actually you don't even need to fetch a User-Instance from the database but can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846537/630877):

```
@login_required
def job_hire(request, account_pk, job_pk):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_pk)
    job.user_id = account_pk
    job.save()
```

---

Edit:

In case you want to keep both user fields and want to associate a job with a user the mechanics are still the same:

```
@login_required
def job_hire(request, account_pk, job_pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=account_pk)
    user.job_history_id = job_pk
    # or:
    # job =get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_pk)
    # user.job_history = job
    user.save()
```

Comment: The user field in the Job model refers to the creator of the job. Even if I created another field identical to the user field but with a different name to keep track of all jobs, I still need this to be stored with each user not each job. @arie

Comment: Okay, this wasn't obvious from looking at your model. Nevertheless connecting users and jobs in the view should still work the same.

Comment: If the same user is hired for two jobs will the line `user.job_history_id = job_pk` save both of them or will the most recently added job override the older one previously stored in the field. @arie

Comment: Hm ... I guess your data model currently doesn't reflect your requirements. `User` has a FK to `Job`, so one job can have multiple users but one user only has one job. If a job can only have one user, I would reverse the relation as I initially proposed. Nothing keeps you from adding another `created_by` field to the `Job` model to indicate the creator. If however jobs can have multiple users and users can have multiple jobs, then you are looking for a `ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: Each user can have many jobs. Each job can only have a user. This is represented by a many to one?

Comment: This is exactly the setup i originally described using the backward relation.
So remove the job field from the user model and add a second field pointing to `User` to your `Job` model: One for the creator and the other to keep track of the job history.

Comment: If I knew a user and wanted to get all his job_history how would I achieve this?

Comment: Like I described in my answer!

Comment: So should I change my Job model to this: `hired_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to accomplish the many to one @arie

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks good so far. What you'll want to do is first create `Job` object.

```
job=Job(user=..., etc.)
job.save()
```

Then you add that job to `User` object.

```
user=User(job_history=job, ...)
user.save()
```