# Why am I getting an integrity error django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I am building a django web app with a custom user model. At the end of the sign up process when I submit the form an integrity error occurs.

Here is the error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.job_history_id
```

This error indicates that the field in the custom user model named job_history cannot be null. However such a field does not even exist.

Here is my custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "password"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

I have no idea what this error is referring to and why it is occurring. I added the field named `job_history` at a previous point but have since deleted it and updated the database accordingly. This error only began to occur when I was fiddling around with the Job and User models in order to achieve a field capable of storing the users previously completed jobs. Further details are available in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933409/how-to-add-object-to-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django) stackoverflow questions.

Why is the integrity error occuring and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate after you removed the job_history field?

Comment: Yes and when I do it just says: `No changes detected` @GagikSukiasyan

Comment: Please try running makemigration, then migrate for your apps, its better start with `manage.py migrate sites` then `manage.py migrate auth`

Comment: Here is the output for both: `python manage.py migrate sites
 --> CommandError: App 'sites' does not have migrations.` And `python manage.py migrate auth --> 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
` @GagikSukiasyan

Comment: I was typing in answer field, the fake initial migration should help in such cases. if it doesn't help go to your DB and delete the column from DB and it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that your job_history field is still in the database and for some reason your migrations didn't work. So you need to look why your migration didn't work. You can try doing fake initial migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate  --fake-initial
```

I'm quite sure this should help, but if this also doesn't help you always can go directly to your DB and delete the job_history_id column from DB

Comment: Since the app isn't deployed yet I just deleted the database, re-ran the migrations and it worked. Thanks.