# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

My **models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    customer_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 64, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 48, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    customer_address = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0) #total price for all products in order
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Заказ %s %s" % (self.id, self.status.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Заказ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Заказы"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My **views.py**.

```
def checkout(request):
    session_key = request.session.session_key
    products_in_basket = ProductInBasket.objects.filter(session_key=session_key, is_active=True)
    form = CheckoutContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("OK")
            data = request.POST
            name = data.get("name", "34343434")
            phone = data["phone"]
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=phone, defaults={"first_name": name})

            order = Order.objects.create(user=user, customer_name=name, customer_phone=phone, status_id=1)
            for name, value in data.items():
                if name.startswith("product_in_basket_"):
                    product_in_basket_id = name.split("product_in_basket_")[1]
                    product_in_basket = ProductInBasket.objects.get(id=product_in_basket_id)

                    product_in_basket.nmb = value
                    product_in_basket.order = order
                    product_in_basket.save(force_update=True)

                    ProductInOrder.objects.create(
                        product=product_in_basket.product, 
                        nmb=product_in_basket.nmb, 
                        price_per_item=product_in_basket.price_per_item, 
                        total_price=product_in_basket.total_price, 
                        order=order
                    )

        else:
            print("ERROR")
    return render(request, 'orders/checkout.html', locals())
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
 32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1rc1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py",   line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1rc1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1rc1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\Desktop\NJB\startup\orders\views.py", line 59, in checkout
    order = Order.objects.create(user=user, customer_name=name, customer_phone=phone, status_id=1)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1rc1-py3.7.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Shuliak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1rc1-py3.7.egg\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

**STATUS MODEL EDDIT**

Maybe problem is here. The problem is appeared after i added some code which you can see in comments. "This last error suggests that the Status with pk=1 already exists, but your previous error suggests the contrary. Please add your Status model to your question; lets see if there are any other conditions to consider.":

```
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 16, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Статус %s" % self.name
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace so we can see what the actual problem is. You pasted a few lines, but its out of context and does not help.

Comment: Also, it is very unusual to use `null=True` with a `CharField`. [read more about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: @Ralf, i add full traceback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the line:

```
order = Order.objects.create(user=user, customer_name=name, customer_phone=phone, status_id=1)
```

<strike>You have to pass a status instance for the field `status` because it is a `ForeignKey` field. Just setting `status_id` to an integer won't work.</strike>

I stand corrected, it can work; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846537/9225671).

Your error probably happens because either `user` (or `user_id`) or `status` (or `status_id`) are referencing instances that don't exist in the related database table.

Are you sure that there is a status with `pk=1`? Does the operation `Status.objects.get(pk=1)` succeed?

Comment: And what i should do ?  How can i fix this ?

Comment: Does the operation `Status.objects.get(pk=1)` succeed?

Comment: If the `Status` instance with `pk=1` does not exist, you need to create it first, or assign a different `Status` instance to your new `Order` instance.

Comment: Status matching query does not exist

Comment: Ok. Create a status with `pk=1` or assign a different status in `Order.objects.create(..., status_id=1)`

Comment: I added that: 
`st = Status.objects.create(pk=1)`
And i have this error:
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
UNIQUE constraint failed: orders_status.id

Comment: I am really sorry that i am wasting your time. But i want to understand what is going on and how to solve problems like this one.

Comment: This last error suggests that the Status with pk=1 already exists, but your previous error suggests the contrary. Please add your `Status` model to your question; lets see if there are any other conditions to consider.

Comment: Plaese edit the code into your question, the format in the comments is not suitable for multiline code

Comment: I add a status model.

Comment: There seems to be nothing strange with your `Status` model. Are you sure that the line `Status.objects.get(pk=1)` raises a `DoesNotExist` error? Or are you sure that `Status.objects.create(pk=1)` raises a "UNIQUE constraint failed" error?

Comment: Yep. It shows this:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: orders_status.id`
Also, i tried to paste that piece of code before that line:
`if request.POST:`
And it gave me error and i couldnt open my checkout.html while runing.
Edit:
Moreover i noticed that i had a problem :
`no such table: mainApp_subscriber` after additing Status code.

Comment: Man, frankly speaking, i cant understand what i have done, but i seemingly solve the problem. I have changed this:
`order = Order.objects.create(user=user, customer_name=name, customer_phone=phone, status_id=1)`
for this:
`order = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=user, customer_name=name, customer_phone=phone, status_id=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the named parameter of `db_constraint` of `models.ForeignKey()` to `False`(by default its `True`) like this:

```
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT,db_constraint=False)
```

This worked for me on a certain project the only issue will be that you will be unable to ensure the integrity of your db (e.g knowing whether all the Status objects referenced actually exist) but it makes sense if you're working with legacy code.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I see you didn't save the instance "order". ---- order.save()

### I think the solution is to save instaces to be saved.

Today, I had the same error message as you did. I realized that I forgot to save an instance in my code.
My code is different from your code, but I think you're worth trying

Comment: I am not confident in English. English may be wrong(+_+)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because I used the wrong form.
Check your code for the form. I don't see where do you use it after `if form.is_valid():` check.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, I forgot to migrate the model when I passed the post instance to the comment model, and before that the instance was Articles

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).