# update foreignkey field in Django

Tags: django, django-1.7

have the following models

```
    Class FootballWebsite(models.Model):
        """Football service website."""
        url = models.URLField(validators=[validate_club_url], unique=True)
        #Football service
        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
        sub_categories = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, default=1)
        
        
    class SubCategory(models.Model):
        """Sub Category"""
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField()

class FootballWebsiteDescription(models.Model):
    """Football service website description."""
    about = models.ForeignKey(Footballwebsite)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    relation = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    language = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    contactInformation = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    officialInfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and trying to execute the following

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        websites = FootballWebsiteDescription.objects.filter(title__in=['title1',' title2'])
        for website in websites:

              try:
                  fc = FootballWebsite.objects.filter(id=website.about_id)
                  fc.sub_categories_id = 88
                  fc.save()
```

and also the following option

```
fc = FootballWebsite.objects.filter(id=website.about_id).update(sub_categories_id=88)
```

to my understanding both ways to update the subcategory id from the default 1 to 88 should work.
i can update other fields this way at least, and see this as an example referenced anywhere.

i can only find this reference [Django: Set foreign key using integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846029/django-set-foreign-key-using-integer) which indicates i might have run into a bug in my very old Django 1.7 project.

Am i missing something very obvious here or is there a work around?
much obliged.

EDIT!!
ended up with the following that works for me.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        websites = FootballWebsiteDescription.objects.filter(title__in=['title1',' title2'])
        for website in websites:

              try:
                  sub_category_instance = SubCategory.objects.get(id=88)
                  fc = FootballWebsite.objects.filter(id=website.about_id,sub_categories_id=1)[0]
                  fc.sub_categories = sub_category_instance
                  fc.sub_categories.save()
                  fc.save()
              except Exception:
                  pass
```

Comment: My first thought would be to change your `fc.sub_categories_id = 88` line to `fc.sub_categories = SubCategory.objects.get(pk=88)`

Comment: thnx, but have tried that, it resorts in the same silent fail however

Comment: If you're getting the same error it's not related to the bug you posted as this should be a workaround as noted by @theptrk's answer. It's likely there's something missing from your question that's causing this behavior. Possible thoughts:  Are you sure sub_category 88 exists? Are you re-writing the `fc` to 1 at another point. Is the save command being redefined causing it to fail further up chain? Django usually doesn't like to fail silently. Especially with DB writes

Comment: well, the same error, the error is it does NOT give an error and also does not update the database. the id 88 does exist, and the 1 is the default value when the record is created. very well possible something is missing in my question, if only i knew what ;)

Comment: Please share your the `FotballWebsiteDescription` model. Furhermore *don't* wrap it in a `try`-`except`.